# Invoking method with array of objects as parameter

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

Hello I'm having issues running my method bugScan which I think is because I've declared myBugs as an array of objects. If any can give me any hints or point me the right direction of sorting this out I would very much appreciate it :) Below is all the appropriate classes:

```
package mainFuncs;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class aBug {

String species, name;
int x, y, energy, id, foodpref;
char symbol;

public void bugScan(aBug[] bugObjects, Scanner scan) {

    String inSpecies, inName;
    int inX, inY, inEnergy, inId;

    for(int i = 0; i < bugObjects.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Species: ");
            inSpecies = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Name: ");
            inName = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("X position: ");
            inX = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Y position: ");
            inY = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Energy: ");
            inEnergy = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("ID: ");
            inId = scan.nextInt();

            bugObjects[i].symbol = '*';
            bugObjects[i].species = inSpecies;
            bugObjects[i].name = inName;
            bugObjects[i].x = inX;
            bugObjects[i].y = inY;
            bugObjects[i].energy = inEnergy;
            bugObjects[i].id = inId;
        }
}
}
```

This is the other class:

```
package mainFuncs;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainMenu {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        aBug[] myBugs = new aBug[5];

        myBugs.bugScan(myBugs, scan);
        System.out.print("hi");
    }
}
```

My issue is occurs at the line: 
myBugs.bugScan(myBugs, scan); 
with the error message "Cannot invoke bugScan(aBug[], Scanner) on the array type aBug[]"

Comment: `myBugs` is an array and does not have any method `bugScan`

Comment: They're both from the same package mainFuncs. I've taken this one issue from a larger program and rewrote to these two classes into their own new package (mainFuncs) to try and single out the issue with this being it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the method in the `aBug` class, but you trying to call it on an array of `aBug` objects! Anyway, I think you can take the `bugScam` method out from the first class and place it inside the second class.

```
package mainFuncs;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class aBug {

    String species, name;
    int x, y, energy, id, foodpref;
    char symbol;
}
```

Second class:

```
package mainFuncs;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainMenu {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        aBug[] myBugs = new aBug[5];

        bugScan(myBugs, scan);
        System.out.print("hi");
    }

    public static void bugScan(aBug[] bugObjects, Scanner scan) {

        String inSpecies, inName;
        int inX, inY, inEnergy, inId;

        for(int i = 0; i < bugObjects.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Species: ");
            inSpecies = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Name: ");
            inName = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("X position: ");
            inX = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Y position: ");
            inY = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Energy: ");
            inEnergy = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("ID: ");
            inId = scan.nextInt();

            bugObjects[i].symbol = '*';
            bugObjects[i].species = inSpecies;
            bugObjects[i].name = inName;
            bugObjects[i].x = inX;
            bugObjects[i].y = inY;
            bugObjects[i].energy = inEnergy;
            bugObjects[i].id = inId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That would require changing the method to a static one however, is that not the best solution?

Comment: @EliasMalik yes. Remember to accept answers, always.

Answer (score 0):

The typ parameter aBug will not be acceptable. By own written classes, the name should be written in camel case, so that could be the case of the exception.

Comment: That's not important in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the line you mentioned!!
`myBugs` is an array and does not have any method `bugScan`

it should be something like this

```
 new aScan().bugScan(myBugs, scan);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :). but would that not cause a NPE?

Comment: I do''t think so :) if there is any you should fix it somehow else! (BTW i just update my answer)

Answer (score 0):

`myBugs` is an array, so you will only be able to perform array operations on it. Your method `bugScan()` is defined inside the `aBug` class. If you want to run it you can solve it by doing:

```
Bug tmp = new aBug();
tmp.bugScan(myBugs, scan);
```

But this smells like bad coding, the aBug class shouldn't have the responsibility the 'scan for bugs'.
On a side note: By convetion class names start with a capital and even if you apply the fix it will throw a NullPointerException because you never initialize your array.